# Whether or not to omit "then" and whether or not to omit "it"

Tags: adverbs

What is the correct way to write? or no is right?

1) Consequently, if the algebra A is not nilsemisimple **it** necessarily contains a non zero nilpotent matrix N and we get the result.

2) Consequently, if the algebra A is not nilsemisimple **,** necessarily contains a non zero nilpotent matrix N and we get the result.

3) Consequently, if the algebra A is not nilsemisimple **, then** necessarily contains a non zero nilpotent matrix N and we get the result.

Comment: Welcome to ELL. Please note that this is not a proofreading service or a writers workshop, though we can help you work through *specific* questions of usage. Which do *you* think is most "correct"? Why do you think the others are less so?

Comment: I believe that it's better to write either *nil-semisimple* or *nil-semi-simple* than *nilsemisimple*. This is a specific kind of ring in mathematics. (See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_%28mathematics%29#Semisimple_rings)

Answer (score 2):

(I'm not a mathematician, so I have to assume that *it* refers to *the algebra*.)

The consequence clause (apodosis, *then* clause) is the main clause in the sentence and **must** have an explicit subject. *Then* is not required at the beginning of this clause.

> If the algebra is not nilsemisimple, **it** necessarily contains ...

However, *then* can be helpful in making your argument clear if the condition clause (protasis, *if* clause) is very long or complex

> If the algebra is not nilsemisimple (and we have already established that in the case at hand the algebra in fact is not nilsemisimple), **then** it necessarily contains ...

Note that a pronoun may *precede* its referent if it falls in a clause subordinate to the clause containing its referent. In a conditional construction the condition clause is subordinate:

> If it is not nilsemisimple the algebra necessarily contains ...

And if the subject of the condition clause  is the same as the subject of the consequence clause AND the condition clause is headed by a form of *BE*, the subject and *BE* may be omitted:

> If not nilsemisimple, the algebra necessarily contains ...

You can also reorganize the sentence, which sometimes makes the referents and the structure of your argument clearer:

> The algebra, if not nilsemisimple, necessarily contains a non-zero nilpotent matrix N ...

And in many cases you can replace this kind of condition clause with a restrictive relative, or even an attributive adjectival:

> An algebra which is not nilsemisimple necessarily contains ...
>   A non-nilsemisimple algebra necessarily contains ...

Answer (score 1):

Since you have two independent clauses:

> the algebra A is not nilsemisimple
>   it necessarily contains a non zero nilpotent matrix N and we get the result

and the second clause is a conclusion based on the first one, you would use the *if...then* format, along with a comma between them.

Also, independent clauses need a subject, in the second one it is *it*.

So:

> Consequently, if the algebra A is not nilsemisimple **, then it** necessarily contains a non zero nilpotent matrix N and we get the result.